# For Loops Time Complexity

Tags: data-structures, time-complexity, big-o

For the given code what's the time complexity in Big-O notation ?

```
for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    for(int j = 1; j <= n; j = j + i)
             some_constant_statement
```

If I'm not wrong

```
First loop take  n times
Second loop n.long(n) time
For Second loop :

n + n/2 + n/3 + n/4 +...................n/n times
n(1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + ..............1/n) times means
n(long(n)) time
So, time complexity of entire piece of code is n.n.long(n)
```

Please correct me guys if I'm wrong .

Comment: H.Das, your reasoning is correct except that you don't have to count first loop, since you already take it into consideration while calculating the number of second loop's operations. It is O(nlogn)

Comment: thanks for correct me !! So the time complexity is n.log(n)

Comment: The linked duplicate is not a duplicate, since the increment of the inner loop is there `1`, not `i`.

Answer (score 3):

**Short answer**: the time complexity is *O(n* log *n)*.

The inner loop each time takes *n* steps. Indeed:

```
for(int j = 1; j <= n; j = j + i)
         some_constant_statement
```

Here `j` always iterates from `1` (inclusive) to `n` (inclusive), so this will perform `n/i` constant statements.

The total number of operations is thus:

```
    n
   ---
   \     1
n  /    ---
   ---   i
   i=1
```

The sum is the [*Harmonic series* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)). We can approximate this with the [*Stirling's approximation* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation). We thus know that:

```
     n                  n
    ---                ---
    \     1            \    1
    /    ---  ≤ ln n ≤ /   ---
    ---  i+1           ---  i
    i=1                i=1
```

So that means that we can state that the total number of operations has time complexity *O(n×ln n)*. Since *log<sub>a</sub>(b) = log a/log b*, we can state this as *O(n* log *n)*